# Is there are any way to send command to printer without printer.BeginDoc/EndDoc?

Tags: delphi, printing

I have a HP receipt printer A799 and it is connect and control one drawer
If there are any printing signal send to printer, the printer will send signal to open the drawer.
There are Two Question.

First Question:

If i have add Printer.BeginDoc and Printer.EndDoc in the program i can successfully to send command to the printer.(I try to send Test Print request to printer, it's success)

But the problem is when i try to send the query command such as ask printer transmit the drawer status to me, it also go to feed the paper one line and open the drawer.

The reason of this action is Printer.BeginDoc and Printer.EndDoc? I try to remove them from my code but the printer and drawer will not do anything when i send any command to printer now.

Second Question:

```
ExtEscape(Printer.Handle, PASSTHROUGH, SizeOf(BufferIN), @BufferIn, 4, @BufferOut)
```

BufferIn and BufferOut also are the PChar
I use this function to take to printer and i have try this function is work(try to test print)

I try to send the query command to printer, but after that BufferOut have not get any return, it's still a null PChar.

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your first question - the second one should be moved to a separate post here, and asked as a separate question.

You can send something to the printer without using BeginDoc/EndDoc by using the [Print Spooler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (from the WinSpool.pas unit) directly. Here's an example of printing a file directly to the printer (posted in one of the old Borland/CodeGear Delphi forums a few years ago by Peter Below of TeamB):

```
uses 
  WinSpool;

procedure PrintFile(const sFileName: string);
const
  BufSize = 16384;
var
  Count, BytesWritten: integer;
  hPrinter: THandle;
  Device : array[0..255] of char;
  Driver : array[0..255] of char;
  Port   : array[0..255] of char;
  hDeviceMode: THandle;
  DocInfo: TDoc_Info_1;
  f: file;
  Buffer: Pointer;
begin
  Printer.PrinterIndex := -1;
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, hDeviceMode);
  if not WinSpool.OpenPrinter(@Device, hPrinter, nil) then exit;
  DocInfo.pDocName := 'MyDocument';
  DocInfo.pOutputFile := nil;
  DocInfo.pDatatype := 'RAW';
  if StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, @DocInfo) = 0 then
  begin
    WinSpool.ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    exit;
  end;
  if not StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) then
  begin
    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
    WinSpool.ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    exit;
  end;
  System.Assign(f, sFileName);
  try
    Reset(f, 1);
    GetMem(Buffer, BufSize);
    while not eof(f) do
    begin
      Blockread(f, Buffer^, BufSize, Count);
      if Count > 0 then
      begin
        if not WritePrinter(hPrinter, Buffer, Count, BytesWritten) then
        begin
          EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
          EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
          WinSpool.ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
          FreeMem(Buffer, BufSize);
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    FreeMem(Buffer, BufSize);
    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
    WinSpool.ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
  finally
    System.Closefile( f );
  end;
end;
```

Here's an example of reading the printer status I found (again by Peter Below of TeamB) - it was tested in Delphi 2007, so it may need some minor tweaks to some of the types for later versions of Delphi:

```
Uses WinSpool;

function GetCurrentPrinterStatus: DWORD;
var
  hPrinter: THandle;
  Device : array[0..255] of char;
  Driver : array[0..255] of char;
  Port   : array[0..255] of char;
  hDeviceMode: THandle;
  bytesNeeded, bytesWritten: Cardinal;
  pPI: PPrinterInfo2;
  Defaults: TPrinterDefaults;
begin
  Assert( Printer.PrinterIndex >= 0 );
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, hDeviceMode);
  FillChar( Defaults, Sizeof(Defaults), 0 );
  Defaults.DesiredAccess:= 
    PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER or PRINTER_ACCESS_USE;
  Win32Check(WinSpool.OpenPrinter(@Device, hPrinter, @Defaults ));
  try
    WinSpool.GetPrinter(
      hPrinter,
      2,
      Nil, 0, @bytesNeeded );
    GetMem( pPI, bytesNeeded );
    try
      Win32Check(WinSpool.GetPrinter(
        hPrinter, 2,
        pPI, bytesNeeded, @bytesNeeded ));
      Result := pPI^.Status;
    finally
      FreeMem( pPI );
    end;
  finally
    WinSpool.ClosePrinter( hPrinter );
  end;
end;
```

The API documentation gives you more information about [PRINTER_INFO_2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the flags it returns. You can check for a specific flag using something like this:

```
if (Status and PRINTER_STATUS_ERROR) <> 0 then
  // Printer is in error status
```

Comment: i just want to know the units that you're using in this code , because the type TDoc_Info_1 is not founded , also Printer .

Comment: @Oussaki: `TDoc_Info_1` is in `WinSpool` (which is shown in my code in both blocks - see the first line of each), and `Printer` is in `Printers`, where all of the standard Delphi printer code is located.

Comment: Okay , and the type (TDoc_Info_1)  is changed in the newer versions of Delphi at least i'm using XE7 so is changed  to TDocInfo1 .